# Is it possible to abuse the sections in which are excluded from signature check in a signed executable?

Tags: windows

Microsoft allows you to sign an executable, and has a list of certificates to validate those signatures.

However it is possible to change the data on a file, while still passing the signature check, allowing you to add or change data in certain parts of it.

Does this pose any security risk?

Quoting from an [old blog post](https://blog.barthe.ph/2009/02/22/change-signed-executable/) (which is still relevant):

> However three areas of a PE executable are excluded from the hash
> computation:
>
> the Checksum in the optional Windows specific header: 4 bytes.
>
> the Certificate Table entry in the optional Windows specific header: 8
> bytes.
>
> the Digital Certificate section at the end of the file: variable
> length.
>
> You should be able to change those area without breaking the
> signature. I have discovered by accident that it is possible to append
> an arbitrary amount of data at the end of the Digital Certificate. The
> data are ignored by both the signature parsing and hash computation
> algorithms. It works on all version of Windows I tested (2000, XP,
> Vista), as long as the length of the Certificate Table is correctly
> increased. The length is stored in two different location: the PE
> header and the beginning of the certificate table.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be high on the list of exploits https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/cybercrime-exploits-digital-certificates/. Maybe to evade scanning https://venafi.com/blog/ssl-attacks-part-1-why-do-cybercriminals-abuse-digital-certificates/. I guess imagine the objectives you could achieve with this and work back?